# How can I query Solr and get multivalued field results returned as a single string?

Tags: solr

I have a Solr query like so:

```
curl "$URL" --silent --show-error \
    -X POST \
    -F 'q=codes:*' \
    -F 'fl=flrid,codes' \
    -F 'rows=2' \
    -F 'wt=json' \
```

And I get results back like so:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"codes:*",
      "fl":"flrid,codes",
      "rows":"2",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":698970,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "codes":["XX:A"],
        "flrid":"1704TS1"},
      {
        "codes":["XX:B","YY:Z"],
        "flrid":"1704TW4"}]
  }}
```

I'd like to get the `codes` multivalued back as a single string like:

```
      {
        "codes":"XX:A",
        "flrid":"1704TS1"},
      {
        "codes":"XX:B YY:Z",
        "flrid":"1704TW4"}
```

I looked in [the docs](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/function-queries.html) for something like a "JOIN" or a "LISTAGG" function like in SQL, but found nothing.

I'm currently post-processing with `jq`

```
jq '.response.docs[] | [.flrid, (.codes|join(","))] | join(",")'
```

but I'd rather skip that step if Solr can do it for me directly.